# MailKit shows mail sent but not received - .NET Core 1.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, mailkit

Following C# code in `VS2017` shows the mail was sent successfully. And I can verify from my `outlook` account's sent box that the email indeed was sent successfully. But on my `Yahoo` account, email is not there even after more than an hour. **Question**: Is something missing in my code here - how can we make it work? **NOTE**: I've verified in my outlook's sent box that both `From` and `To` mail addresses are correct. I'm following this [Technet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37534.send-email-using-asp-net-core-1-1-with-mailkit-in-visual-studio-2017.aspx).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        //From Address
        string FromAddress = "myfromEmail@hotmail.com";
        string FromAdressTitle = "Email from ASP.NET Core 1.1";
        //To Address
        string ToAddress = "myToEmail@yahoo.com";
        string ToAdressTitle = "Microsoft ASP.NET Core";
        string Subject = "Hello World - Sending email using ASP.NET Core 1.1";
        string BodyContent = "ASP.NET Core was previously called ASP.NET 5. It was renamed in January 2016. It supports cross-platform frameworks ( Windows, Linux, Mac ) for building modern cloud-based internet-connected applications like IOT, web apps, and mobile back-end.";

        //Smtp Server
        string SmtpServer = "smtp.live.com";
        //Smtp Port Number
        int SmtpPortNumber = 587;

        var mimeMessage = new MimeMessage();
        mimeMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(FromAdressTitle, FromAddress));
        mimeMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(ToAdressTitle, ToAddress));
        mimeMessage.Subject = Subject;
        mimeMessage.Body = new TextPart("plain")
        {
            Text = BodyContent

        };

        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {

            client.Connect(SmtpServer, SmtpPortNumber, false);
            // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
            // Error 5.5.1 Authentication 
            client.Authenticate(FromAddress, "myFromEmailpassword");
            client.Send(mimeMessage);
            Console.WriteLine("The mail has been sent successfully !!");
            Console.ReadLine();
            client.Disconnect(true);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after an hour, I received the email on my yahoo account. Not sure why it took more than an hour for yahoo but outlook sent it right away. Thanks to those who may have tried to help but probably did not find an error in the code.

**Observation**: In the received email I can see, in the `To` field the `ToAdressTitle` as `Microsoft ASP.NET Core` (as expected from the code above). But in the `From` field I see only the `FromAddress` and not the `FromAdressTitle` as `Email from ASP.NET Core 1.1` (shown in the code above). I wonder why?

Comment: Yahoo and other webmail servers sometimes re-write the From headers. Also, MailKit has no control over how long it takes Yahoo to send the message out - it shouldn't have taken an hour, but who knows what Yahoo Mail was doing?